# Does the cost of an ENIG-finished PCB depend on the surface area of the exposed gold at a large scale?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, best-practice

At very large quantities (>100k-1M), does the cost of an ENIG plated PCB increase as the surface area of the part exposed to gold increases? Intuitively it would make sense, as more gold would be consumed in the bath to coat a pcb that is just a large ground plane exposed, as opposed to one with just the component footprints. But any website I looked at for quotes would not show a change in the price depending on the PCB Design.

Comment: Things are looked over manually by an engineer anyway and they would have questions if you do something that is unexpected and the power to decline a job.

Comment: It is unlikely you will get a good quote for the quantities you mention from an interface on a website. For anything over a few hundred pieces, it might be worth talking to the mfg directly.

Comment: At those quantities, I you get personal service with people who remember your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely. If you work out the cost in gold at current wholesale prices (about $60/g) for 1u" thick gold layer it's around USD 30 per \$\text m^2\$. Probably costs the manufacturer a bit more than that, plus there's the nickel layer to be applied.

Some manufacturers will ask for an adder if you request more than the pads to be gold plated even in prototype quantities.